# Наложение иконки на изображение

Tags: html, css, hover, img, grid

Крч, дело такое, верстаю себе лендинг, и тут откуда не возьмись появился в..... К делу, надо чтоб при :hover на картинку, на ней появлялась иконка и затемнение, это я сделать могу легко и за 30 секунд, дело в другом, как поместить иконку на картинку с помощью грид и ещё чего-нить, но не посредством маргинов и posA.

Comment: можно на svg это сделать

Comment: Добавьте пример кода

Answer (score 0):

Оно?

```css
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 300px;
}

.bg{
    display: none;
}

.wrapper:hover .bg {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 right:0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6)
}

.icon{
 color: #fff;
}
  
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"> 
    <img src="https://kartinki.detki.today/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/kartinka-dlya-detey-lev-1150x863.jpg">
 <div class="bg">
   <div class="icon">иконка</div>
 </div>
</div>
```